# How to convert Char[] or String to Char* for initialize SecureString in C#?

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

I'm trying to initialize SecureString and I need Char* for that.
I tried to do it with block of unsafe code:

```
unsafe {
    char[] c = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };
    char* pointer = &(c[0]);
    SecureString sec = new SecureString(pointer, 4);
}
```

When try this I got this error:

> Error: You can only take the address of an unfixed expression inside
>   of a fixed statement initializer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just loop through each char and use AppendChar?

```
string s = "Hello";
SecureString ss = new SecureString();

foreach(char c in s) ss.AppendChar(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

They say you shouldn't use that constructor.

You should do this.

```
char[] chars = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };
SecureString sec = new SecureString();
foreach (var c in chars) {
    sec.AppendChar(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted answer says, the accepted way is to use a loop and `AppendChar`. For convenience I've created the following extension method:

```
public static SecureString FromClearString(this SecureString secureString, string clearString)
{
    secureString.Clear();
    clearString.ToList().ForEach(secureString.AppendChar);
    secureString.MakeReadOnly();
    return secureString;
}
```

I use it as follows, eg:

```
var pwd = new SecureString();
await _security.LoginAsync("some.random.user", pwd.FromClearString("the.password"), Cts.Token);
```